# regex to filter strings that dont contain '/'

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am using jsZip to scan for .csv files in the root . The array I get is in the following format

["xyz.csv","abc.py","aa/abc.txt","aa/fg.txt"...]

output expected= ["xyz.csv"]

so the 2 conditions are

1. It must not include '/'
2. it mustend with .csv

How to combine these 2 conditions and check if .csv exist in root?

Comment: `abc.py` doesn't end with `.csv` so it fails the condition

Comment: something like `/^[^\/]*\.csv$/`, but is untested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const items = ["xyz.csv", "abc.py", "aa/abc.txt", "aa/fg.txt"]

const filtered = items.filter(item => item.match(/^[^/]+\.csv$/))
console.log(filtered)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I can filter required files now.

Answer (score 2):

```js
files.filter(filePath => {
  return !filePath.includes('/') && filePath.endsWith('.csv');
});
```

You can simply filter using any conditions you'd like applied to the `filePath`. The ones you've asked for are shown in the above example.

Comment: More often than not, by introducing a regular expression you're adding to your problem. Good answer!

Answer (score 1):

Your regex would look like this:

```
\/.*\.csv$
```

- `\/` matches a forward slash character. The forward slash needs to be escaped with a backslash because it's a special character in regex.
- `.*` matches any number of characters (including zero characters) between the forward slash and the file extension.
- `\.csv` matches the '.csv' file extension. The dot needs to be escaped with a backslash because it's a special character in regex.
- `$` matches the end of the string.

Putting it all together, this regular expression matches strings that include at least one forward slash and end with the '.csv' file extension.